# Fake internet connection on iOS simulator

Tags: iphone, caching, ios-simulator

I'm using Charles Proxy to redirect web requests to a local folder for an app I'm making. However it seems that NSURLConnection checks for an internet connection before attempting to download. How does it perform this check and can I fake the connection being there, because I know it will be able to download the content from the local cache. Or is there a better way of doing this?

EDIT: Actually all I need to do is connect to a fake Wifi hotspot on my laptop, I tried connecting to a BTFON hotspot, which redirects you to a login page for every request until you login (therefore appearing the laptop is connected to the internet, but effectively its not) and it worked when I had Charles proxy enabled. Now I just need to find some software that can connect to Fake Wifi Hotspot, or have a virtual second Wifi adapter, create a adhoc network and connect to that (in a kind of loop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it seems OSX can do this out the box. The answer is quite simple to make it appear your connected to a WiFi network, just create a adhoc (computer-to-computer) network from the Mac, you don't need to connect any other devices but it means that your computer appears connected to the internet to Laptop and iOS simulator.

So now I can download a copy of the data I need, set up redirects in [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) (<- amazing software btw) create a adhoc network and still develop my app while I'm not connected to the internet (even though it requires the internet to function)

Comment: I followed these steps and it stil fails for me. It detects there is no internet connection :/ I guess it's RestKit's fault maybe..?

Answer (score 2):

as an idea, why don't you use your own web server?

just change the hosts file so you have a full name domain, like: `http://mywebserver.local` and use that in your connections, you can also provide information using the same technique.

in your program just add a DEBUG clause that would use `http://mywebserver.local` instead the full path.

Answer (score 0):

You could try simply loading the HTML directly from your application bundle, after creating a URL via the fileURLWithPath: method.

Apple have a [Technical Q&A](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1630.html) that shows this in operation. (See the first code listing "Loading a document into a UIWebView".)

Comment: It would require a lot of code modification, and the code that downloads the data is not mine, and I don't have time right now to fully understand it

Comment: @Jonathan Sorry - I thought you were trying to load content from a local resource.

Comment: @middaparka Well I guess I am just in a roundabout way.

Comment: @Jonathan Based on your question update, all I'll say is that what you're attempting sounds like a very odd approach if you're just trying to load some locally stored HTML. It might be an idea to ask a new question along the lines of "How can I..." to get a consensus of some good approaches to try. Whilst you might have to ditch a lot of code, it could well save you a lot of pain in the long run. (For example, if the user puts their device into airplane mode, or disables their Wi-Fi, I suspect your current approach will break.)

Comment: @middaparka, it's because the app is meant to download data from the internet and I'm using a SDK to get that data from the stackexchange APIs. but I'm going on a long car journey today and don't want to waste the time, and I don't have a dongle so I won't have internet, but rather than modify the code just for this journey, and risk errors later I'd rather simulate the internet.

Comment: @Jonathan Ah. I see. Feel free to ignore all of the above then. :-)